# Swift SpriteKit use struct instead of class to render sprites

Tags: swift, struct, skspritenode

I have been updating my game recently to use more value types. I am still not 100% confident with weak and unowned in some cases so I went the struct way to avoid strong reference cycles. As per apples newer keynotes it seems value types are they way to go for the most part anyway.

I have never seen an example where structs are used to render sprites in a spriteKit game so I wonder what the drawbacks are. 
I understand that they are copied and not referenced but for my usage it seems to work.

So basically is there something I need to watch out for when doing this

```
struct Flag {
   let post: SKSpriteNode
   let flag: SKSpriteNode

  init(postImage: String, flagImage: String) {
     post = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: postImage)
     // other set ups for post sprite

     flag = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: flagImage)
     // other set ups for flag sprite
     post.addChild(flag)
   }

   func animate() {
       // code to animate flag
   }
}
```

Than in my SKScenes I simply add them as usual

```
 let flag = Flag(postImage: "FlagPostImage", flagImage: "FlagImage")
 flag.post.position = ...
 addChild(flag.post)
 flag.animate()
```

Now even if I create multiple flags in the same scene I seem to have no problems with this way.
I am just curious because I have never really seen an example like this so I wonder if I am missing something, like performance drawbacks etc.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well one of the drawbacks is it makes your code less readable.  You are only adding the post object located inside of the struct into the scene, but then you animate the entire flag object.  If your flag struct was black-boxed,  people would ask "Why do I only add the post and not the flag to the scene".  Another drawback is at times you want multiple references to hang around, especially if you're doing tests like `if isKindOf SKPhysicsContact` to determine if you'ee dealing with a `SKPhysicsContact`, then you can have a function that can handle SKPhysicsContact without creating a new object,

Comment: Personally I avoid creating `Structs` that contain `Classes`. Because `Structs` copy, each and every copy that get's passed around your app will increase the reference count of the `Classes`. This makes it harder to manage them instead of easier.

Comment: Thank you R Menke, your answer makes total sense, and I will avoid structs in the future that contain classes. I knew it couldn't be that easy and Im glad for your answer because I would have actually made my life harder. I am still quite a novice and sometimes just think of classes that I create my self, forgetting that things such as SKSpriteNode are also treated as classes for reference counting etc. If you want you can copy your comment into an answer and i will mark it as correct. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I avoid creating `Structs` that contain `Classes`. Because `Structs` copy, each and every copy that get's passed around your app will increase the reference count of the `Classes`. This makes it harder to manage them instead of easier.

It is also useful to take a look at how `UIKit` uses `Structs`. A `UIView` is an object but has many defining properties that are `Structs`. For example it's `frame`.

Drop the code below in a playground to see some effects of this behaviour.
The `protocol` is just to get some meaningful feedback form the playground.

```
protocol IDLookable : CustomPlaygroundQuickLookable {

    var id : Int { get set }

}

extension IDLookable {

    func customPlaygroundQuickLook() -> PlaygroundQuickLook {
        return PlaygroundQuickLook.AttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "\(self.dynamicType) with id : \(self.id)"))
    }
}


class MyClass : IDLookable {

    var id : Int = 0

    init(id : Int) {
        self.id = id
    }
}

struct MyContainerStruct : IDLookable {

    var id : Int = 0
    var object : MyClass

    init(id : Int, object:MyClass) {
        self.id = id
        self.object = object
    }
}

class Scope {

    // ref count = 1
    var object = MyClass(id: 11)
    var structContainer : MyContainerStruct

    init() {
        // ref count = 2
        structContainer = MyContainerStruct(id: 222, object: object)
        messWithAClassInAStruct()
    }

    func messWithAClassInAStruct() {

        // ref count = 3
        var structContainerTwo = structContainer
        structContainerTwo.id = 333
        structContainerTwo.object // 11

        // altering the object in one struct will obvously update all references
        structContainerTwo.object.id = 1
        structContainer.object // 1
        structContainerTwo.object // 1

    }
}

let test = Scope()
```

---

One pattern that does make it easy to work with `Reference Types` in `Value Types` is to store them as `weak optionals` in the `Value Types`. This means that something will need to have a `strong reference` but chances are that some `Class` will be responsible for creating the `Structs` this is a good place to keep that `strong reference`.

```
struct MyContainerStruct : IDLookable {

    var id : Int = 0
    weak var object : MyClass?

    init(id : Int, object:MyClass) {
        self.id = id
        self.object = object
    }
}

class Scope {

    // ref count = 1
    var object = MyClass(id: 11)
    var structContainer : MyContainerStruct

    init() {
        // ref count = 1
        structContainer = MyContainerStruct(id: 222, object: object)
        messWithAClassInAStruct()
    }

    func messWithAClassInAStruct() {
        // ref count = 1
        var structContainerTwo = structContainer
        structContainerTwo.id = 333
        structContainerTwo.object // 11
    }
}

let test = Scope()
```

Comment: Awesome answer, very detailed. Thank you very much